# url invalid when trying to access a file on disk

Tags: file, url, fusioncharts

Hi I am rendering a map using setDataURL("path to map xml"),
currently when I give a path which a valid URL only then does the Map load.
If I give the path as a disk location , it doesnt work since it just appends this path to the base URL which makes it an invalid URL.
so if the path is /myapp/js/my1.xml - it works as I have my js folder in web-app directory so http://localhost:xxx/myapp/js/my1.xml is valid

if the path is like C:/xmls/my1.xml - it doesnt work since http://localhost:xxx/myapp/C:/xmls/my1.xml is invalid URL.
but since we are deploying a war we want to keep the XML outside the web-app , how do I set the path in setDataURL() method.

Thanks & Regards
Priyank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primarily you can try using file:/// protocol, but I fear that might not of much help if you application is running in a webserver.

This is likely to cause a cross domain issue and the file content will get blocked.

Comment: I will test if this  works but theres something with flash sandbox security model which doesnt allow resources from different domains and the xml is a data input to the flash chart